# c++ calendar program format, display, offset

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in c++ that will print a calendar for the entire year. The program will ask the user what year they want to enter so it may determine if it is a leap year. It will then ask the user to ask what day would they want they January 1<sup>st</sup> to start counting from. It should then cout every single day of January and then move to February then count every single day then move on to march etc. However it does not print every month correctly. I also am required to not use the `%` operator. Any help that could make my program print a proper calendar would be much appreciated and please do not post suggestions that use the `%` operator.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
/****************************************************************************************
                             Prototypes
****************************************************************************************/
void getyear(int& year , int& days_per_yr);
void list_months(int imonth, int iyear);
void firstday(int& mostart);
void start_month(int& mostart);
int get_numdays(int xmonth, int numdays, int year);
void listdays(int numdays, int& mostart);
bool isLeapYear(int year);
void printMonth();
/****************************************************************************************
                           Main
****************************************************************************************/
int main(){    
printMonth();
}

void printMonth(){ // calls all the functions needed to print the calendar
    int year;
    int day;
    int month;
    int mostart;
    int days_per_yr; 
    int numdays; // number of days per month is stored here
    cout << "What year do you want a calendar for? ";
    getyear(year, days_per_yr);   
    cout << "What day of the week does January 1 fall ";
    cout <<"on (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, etc.)? ";
    firstday(mostart);
    cout << year << "\n" <<endl;
    for (month=1; month <= 12; ++month){
    list_months(month, year);
    start_month(mostart);
    numdays=get_numdays(month, numdays, year);
    listdays(numdays, mostart);
    }
}







void getyear(int& year, int& days_per_yr){ //gets the year from the user and sends it back to the printMonth function
                         // this function is vital for the isLeapyear function to work properly
    cin >> year;
    if (isLeapYear(year) == true){
    days_per_yr = 366;}
    else{
    days_per_yr = 365;}
}








void list_months(int imonth, int iyear){ // lists every month needed with the days spaced out correctly
    switch (imonth){
    case 1: cout<< "        January" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"-----------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 2: cout<< "        Febuarry" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"-----------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 3: cout<< "        March" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"------------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 4: cout<< "        April" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"------------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 5: cout<< "        May" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"------------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 6: cout<< "        June" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"------------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 7: cout<< "        July" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"------------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 8: cout<< "        August" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"------------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 9: cout<< "        September" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"------------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 10: cout<< "        October" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"------------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 11: cout<< "        November" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"------------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    case 12: cout<< "        December" << endl;
    cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl;
    cout <<"------------------------"<< endl;
    break;
    }
}






void firstday(int& mostart){ // gets the input from the user for the start_month(); function

    cin >> mostart;
    cout <<"\n";
    }






void start_month(int& mostart){ //does the spacing so that the desired day entered by the user is displayed correctly

    if(mostart==0){
     cout << setw(3);
     }
     else if (mostart == 1){
     cout << setw(6);
     }
     else if (mostart == 2){
     cout << setw(9);
     }
     else if (mostart == 3){
     cout << setw(12);
     }
     else if (mostart == 4){
     cout << setw(15);
     }
     else if (mostart == 5){
     cout << setw(18);
     }
     else if (mostart == 6){
     cout << setw(21);
     }
     else if (mostart == 7){
     mostart = 1;
     }

     }







int get_numdays(int xmonth, int numdays, int year){ // sets correct amount of days per month. If there is a leap year febuarry will have 29 days.
    if ( xmonth == 1)
    numdays = 31;
    else if ( xmonth == 2){if (isLeapYear(year) == true)
    numdays = 29;
    else
    numdays = 28;}
    else if ( xmonth == 3)
    numdays = 31;
    else if ( xmonth == 4)
    numdays = 30;
    else if ( xmonth == 5)
    numdays = 31;
    else if ( xmonth == 6)
    numdays = 30;
    else if ( xmonth == 7)
    numdays = 31;
    else if ( xmonth == 8)
    numdays = 31;
    else if ( xmonth == 9)
    numdays = 30;
    else if ( xmonth == 10)
    numdays = 31;
    else if ( xmonth == 11)
    numdays = 30;
    else if ( xmonth == 12)
    numdays = 31;
    return numdays;
}






void listdays(int numdays, int& mostart){ //This function counts out every single day depending on the month.
    int oneday;

    for (oneday=1; oneday <= numdays; ++oneday){
    if(mostart <= 6){
    cout << oneday <<"  ";
    mostart++;
    }
    else{
     cout << endl;
     mostart=0;
     start_month(mostart);

     cout << oneday <<"  ";
     mostart++;
    } 
    };


    cout << endl;
    }











bool isLeapYear(int year){ //determines if the year entered is a leapyear or not if it is a leap year it will return true
                           // if true is returned then it will execute a condition that will make febuary a day longer.
                           // If the condition returns false then febuary will continue to be 28 days.
    if (year % 400 == 0){    
    return true;
    }

    if (year % 100 == 0){    
    return false;
    }
    if (year % 4 == 0){
    return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: Off topic: `cout << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S  "<< endl; cout <<"-----------------------"<< endl;` is common to all cases and can be pulled out to save you a whole lot of redundant code

Comment: `isLeapYear` **uses** the `%` operator, so... why do you ask not to post solutions that use it?  Is the quiz for you or or all of us?  Also, weekday for january 1st is completely determined by the year.

Comment: Just use Julian Day Number formula and do not bother with that convoluted logics details there - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

Comment: @LuisColorado  You don't need `%` if the year is an int: `bool isLeapYear(int year) { return (year/400*400==year || year/100*100!=year) && year/4*4==year; }`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, i know that, My question was because the OP wants us to do the hard work of not using `%` operator, but then he uses it in the code he posts.  Is there no Justice in this World? :)

Answer (score 0):

The cheap hack:

In `start_month` make sure you print out a character to move the stream

```
cout << setw(2) << " "; // was setw(3), but we added a manual space.
```

because we're about to use `setw(2)` in `listdays` to always print out 2 characters for every day number, and that will eliminate the `setw` in `start_month`

```
cout << setw(2) << oneday << "  ";
```

Then make sure everything lines up by adding in spaces and padding  as required.

## edit

OK. Maybe that's confusing. Here's the problem: `cout << oneday <<"  ";` prints out an integer. The first 9 are one digit wide. The next 20 or so are 2 digits wide. In order to line up 1 digit numbers with 2 digit numbers the 1 digit numbers must take up 2 digits of space.

So let's do that, shall we?

```
void listdays(int numdays, int& mostart){ //This function counts out every single day depending on the month.
    int oneday;

    for (oneday=1; oneday <= numdays; ++oneday){
    if(mostart <= 6){
    cout << setw(2) << oneday <<"  ";
    mostart++;
    }
    else{
     cout << endl;
     mostart=0;
     start_month(mostart);

     cout << setw(2) << oneday <<"  ";
     mostart++;
    } 
    };


    cout << endl;
    }
```

But that breaks `start_month` because `cout << setw(2) << oneday <<"  ";` is just going to reset the width set by `cout << setw(3);` and his friends. Quick solution: we need to set the write width and then write a character to take up that space.

```
void start_month(int& mostart){ //does the spacing so that the desired day entered by the user is displayed correctly

    if(mostart==0){
     cout << setw(2) << " ";
     }
     else if (mostart == 1){
     cout << setw(6) << " ";
     }
     else if (mostart == 2){
     cout << setw(10) << " ";
     }
     else if (mostart == 3){
     cout << setw(14) << " ";
     }
     else if (mostart == 4){
     cout << setw(18) << " ";
     }
     else if (mostart == 5){
     cout << setw(22) << " ";
     }
     else if (mostart == 6){
     cout << setw(26) << " ";
     }
     else if (mostart == 7){
     mostart = 1;
     }

     }
```

Now if you really want to kick, you say, "Screw all these `if`/`else if` blocks" and use math. Look at the width numbers above 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26. See the pattern? `2 + mostart * 4`. Don't need no steenking function for that! I might have the wrong staring condition or stride. That's easy to fix. Change one number.

Most of OP's conditional logic can be replaced by simple math. That's why I call the original cut of this answer cheap hack.

The rest is realigning all of the string literals. If OP can't figure that out, I can't help them.

Comment: could you explain more? your answer is very vague and doesn't provide any clarity. Following those instructions messed up my program even more.

Comment: I just did, but it got eaten. Not sure what happened. One minute I was typing away, and the next [my computer was playing this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIMb3hGzWW8). Must have hit a hotkey button and loaded a shortcut because that's totally the kind of thing I have in my shortcuts.